# Hibernate `LazyInitializationException` in local tomcat but not in K8s pods

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have this exception my local tomcat but not k8s pods, did add `@Transactional` and didn't work could you please someone help me on this

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.domain.acc.AccContractGroup.accContractCollection, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:602) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:581) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:303) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.3.Final.jar:5.4.3.Final]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1821) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:408) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:501) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationConcurrencyChecker.isPassiveLocked(AccommodationConcurrencyChecker.java:155) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationConcurrencyChecker$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$172f4172.invoke(<generated>) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationConcurrencyChecker$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c9d66a20.isPassiveLocked(<generated>) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationContractGroup.findOrCreateContractGroup(AccommodationContractGroup.java:163) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationContractGroup.getUpdatableContract(AccommodationContractGroup.java:122) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationContractGroup$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8af049bd.invoke(<generated>) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:684) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.AccommodationContractGroup$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a08f89e1.getUpdatableContract(<generated>) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.service.Impl.AccommodationServiceImpl.updateContract(AccommodationServiceImpl.java:225) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy519.updateContract(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.extention.AccommodationServiceAdapter.updateContract(AccommodationServiceAdapter.java:182) [classes/:]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.extention.AccommodationServiceAdapter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$21d34c53.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) [spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) [spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.extention.AccommodationServiceAdapter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d566dd43.updateContract(<generated>) [classes/:]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.accomsetup.v2.channel.AccommodationContractServiceAdapter.updateContract(AccommodationContractServiceAdapter.java:81) [rest-tbx-connector-tc.jar:]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.accomsetup.v2.controller.AccomContractController.updateAccomContract(AccomContractController.java:191) [classes/:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:919) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket%20-%20Copy.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.service.base.v2.config.filters.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:23) [base-service-2.40.1-FC-0000-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.service.base.v2.config.filters.VisibilityControlFilter.doFilterInternal(VisibilityControlFilter.java:72) [base-service-2.40.1-FC-0000-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.service.base.v2.config.filters.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:38) [base-service-2.40.1-FC-0000-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.v2.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilterInternal(LoggingFilter.java:132) [x-base-service-extensions-6.7.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.v2.security.authorization.filter.AccessControlFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessControlFilter.java:48) [base-service-security-1.0-TB-1170-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.v2.filters.AuthFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthFilter.java:41) [base-service-security-1.0-TB-1170-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at it.codegen.tbx.api.v2.filters.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:94) [x-base-service-extensions-6.7.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.19]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.19]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

Getting response as this

`failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.codegen.tbx.accomsetupservice.domain.acc.AccContractGroup.accContractCollection, could not initialize proxy - no Session",` . Is this because of Hibernate Session close how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same exception in `@OneToMany` relationship when I was trying **delete operation**, by changing lazy fetching to eager fetching did solve my problem:
`fetch = FetchType.LAZY` to `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`
I hope this help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).